# java StAX parser: not preserving double quotes for attributes

Tags: java, xml, attributes, stax

StAX parser is converting the **double quotes** around attributes to **single quotes** in the data model used by `XMLEventReader`. This is fine, but If I want to print back the XML, perhaps selecting only a fragment of the original XML, the output will not be the same.

Input file:

```xml
<root>
  <mySubTrees>
    <mySubTree>
      <a property="target">
        <aa>123</aa>
      </a>
      <b>456</b>
      <c>789</c>
    </mySubTree>
  </mySubTrees>
</root>
```

Code:

```java
@Test
public void test_getXmlFragment() throws Exception {
  byte[] fileContent = getXMLBytes();
  String xmlFragment = "";

  XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
  XMLEventReader eventReader = factory.createXMLEventReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent));
  while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
    XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();
    xmlFragment += event;
  }

  System.out.println(xmlFragment);
}

private byte[] getXMLBytes() throws IOException {
  InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResource(PREFIX_XML_FILES + "/sss.xml").openStream();
  byte[] fileContent = new byte[inputStream.available()];
  inputStream.read(fileContent);
  inputStream.close();
  return fileContent;
}
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="null" encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<root>
    <mySubTrees>
        <mySubTree>
            <a property='target'>
                <aa>123</aa>
            </a>
            <b>456</b>
            <c>789</c>
        </mySubTree>
    </mySubTrees>
</root>
```

Desired Output:

```xml
<?xml version="null" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <mySubTrees>
        <mySubTree>
            <a property="target">
                <aa>123</aa>
            </a>
            <b>456</b>
            <c>789</c>
        </mySubTree>
    </mySubTrees>
</root>
```

Is there any way how to fine-tune this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no difference between an attribute wrapped in single quotes or in double quotes, and it is an unreasonable requirement to demand a difference between the two.

StAX's job is not to preserve the XML file syntax it is reading. StAX is a parser, its job is to relay the data model expressed in the XML it is reading. And it is doing this job perfectly.

A requirement like yours is likely to force you to write your own XML library, because you shouldn't have this requirement in the first place.

Comment: unfortunately the system reading these files needs the double quotes and I've had to resort to using xslt and <xsl:copy-of /> templates to get around this i.e. to preserve the syntax before and after parsing. Is there a better way?

essentially all I need to do is:
1) read xml file
2) split it up - one file per subtree under certain parent nodes

thanks

Comment: @w.l. It's weird that XSLT was capable to do it, but if the goal is to have double-quotes, rather than to preserve the same quotes as the original, then you could have just used any XML outputting technology and instructing it to put double-quotes around attributes. It's often an available cosmetic feature. As I said, though, that's an unreasonable requirements, and no professional toolchain will encourage you with it. If you could hack your way around it and it's secure, then that was the most efficient to do. Otherwise, all you can do is write your own tool.

Comment: **-1** because the answer is no sense to the question.
The question it is pointing out why `StAX` do not satisfy the *reflective* property. Reading from an XML document which uses double quotes on attributes, if you print back again the `XMLEventReader`, it will print in single quotes. And doesn't seem there is a way to tell to XMLEventReader to use double quotes.
I think `StAX` do a great job, nevertheless the requirement of being able to produce the same initial xml is not a bad requirement.